# I can't access to the function in IIFE, it returns undefined to me

Tags: javascript

I have two iife's ,cartParent and ShowCart;I want to access to the showCart from cartParent but I can't get  showCart.addItemToShow(obj) from inside of cartParent codes, it returns undefined, this is my code:

```
var cartParent=(function(addTocart,showCart,Product){
         var  total=0;
            return{
              totalCalc:function(qty){


           $.get("../products.txt",function(data,status,xhr) 
            {

                  if(status=="success"){
                    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
                    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i, e){
                        if(e.id==id){
                            console.log(e.id);
                            var price=e.price;
                            var name=e.name;
                            var desc=e.desc;
                            var img=e.img;
                        var obj= item(id,name,price,qty);

                         showCart.addItemToShow(obj);

                        }

                    })

                  }

              })
            }

        }


})(addTocart,showCart,Product);

 var showCart=(function(){

     return{
        addItemToShow:function(obj){
          console.log("obj:"+obj.price)
        }

     }

  })();
```

Comment: Put the declaration of showCart Before cartParent. Since you use variables, they are defined in the order they are written in instead of being hoisted to the top. So showCart is still undefined when the IIFE runs, since it was only declared, not assigned the result of the other IIFE yet.

Comment: I've tried that before but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks you are right